# PowerPoint VBA - Run Macro When Slide Changes in Edit Mode

Tags: vba, macros, microsoft-powerpoint

I know I could do the following to run code when the slide is changed in presentation mode -

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange()
Dim i As Integer
i = ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.CurrentShowPosition
If i <> 1 Then Exit Sub
'Code that should happen when slide changes goes here
End Sub
```

I'm wanting to know if it is possible to do this when ever a slide is changed outside of the slideshow i.e. the presentation is in edit mode so if I clicked on another slide it would run the code. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably do something along the lines of:

1) Trap the SelectionChange event

2) When the event fires, check to see that the current slide is not the same as it was the last time you trapped a SelectionChange event (because the event fires when you select different shapes as well as different slides).

3) If it's a different slide, run your code and record the index of the current slide (to check against the next time the event fires)

You'd need to do this in an add-in.

The SlideSelectionChanged event might be a better one to respond to, though.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff745869.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was hoping to avoid the need to use an add in but having looked around the internet I guessed this was heading that way. Thanks for the confirmation though!